# Regex: matching exact number occurrences of backslash in string

Tags: regex, powershell

I have data which are paths to files with different depth, for example:

```
Dir1\Dir2\file1.ext
Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\file2.ext
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to filter that paths which are exact depth level. For now, I want to have only that paths which are level 2 of depth:

```
Dir1\Dir2\*
```

I'm using Powershell to find that match. What I've created is this:

```
'[0-9a-zA-Z]*\\{1}[0-9a-zA-Z]*\\{1}[0-9a-zA-Z]*'
```

Which I was think that is: any quantity of letters and numbers, then one backslash, again any of letters and numbers, one more backslash, and finally any quantity of letters and numbers. I was thinking that I will find string with just two backslashes inside, but when I checked it with name with three backslashes inside:

```
PS > "Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\file1.ext" -match '[0-9a-zA-Z]*\\{1}[0-9a-zA-Z]*\\{1}[0-9a-zA-Z]*'
```

I got positive match too, which I was thinking that shouldn't work. How big was my disappointment. Where is my mistake or misunderstanding? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use anchors - `'^[0-9a-zA-Z]+\\[0-9a-zA-Z]+\\[0-9a-zA-Z]+$'`

Comment: Wiktor thank you for your answer. I forget mention about files have extensions too. Sorry for that.

Comment: Yes, that is really not that relevant to the question. It is as easy as adding `\.[0-9a-zA-Z]+` at the end before `$`. Or `\.\w+`

Comment: Yes, that's true. Anyway your answer helps me a lot with this particular case. And I'm grateful for that :)